# Parsing text letter by letter

Tags: pgf-core

The `PGF` package has a module named `parser` that can parse a block of text from an initial state to a final state letter by letter.

For example, the following MWE will parse a given text and count the "Z's", ignore the `b's` and highlight the `a's`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepgfmodule{parser}
\begin{document}
\newcount\mycount

\pgfparserdef{myparser}{initial}{the letter Z}{\advance\mycount by 1\relax Z}
\pgfparserdef{myparser}{initial}{the letter a}{\hl{a}}
\pgfparserdef{myparser}{initial}{the letter b}{} % do nothing
\pgfparserdef{myparser}{initial}{the letter c}{\pgfparserswitch{final}}% done!

\pgfparserparse{myparser}ZZZZaabaabaZbabbbbbabaabcccc%

There are \the\mycount\ Z's.

\end{document}
```

The code will trigger an error if in the sample text an unknown letter is included (I would like it just to be ignored). Is there a short hand way to define such an action or I would need to define all the letters?

Comment: I never did figure out how to make that parser useful. I also want to know the answer to this.

Comment: @RyanReich The manual does not give much info. I have been battling to get it to accept a blank space, where it states as long as the character is represented by meaning it should work. Maybe the German version of the manual gives more info.

Comment: @Yiannis: "Unknown" here means what?

Comment: @AhmedMusa For example the letter `A` hasn't been defined using `\pgfparserdef` and leads to errors.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides: Must it be done via `pgf`?

Comment: The blank space thing was what got me also; I figured that I just didn't know the correct `\meaning` (it is rather tricky to get). I wonder if the parser doesn't accept spaces correctly?

Comment: Continuing on Ahmed's question: If a non-pgf solution is ok, is it ok to require the text that you parse to be given as a macro argument?

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch That's cheating:)

Comment: @RyanReich The `\meaning` of a blank space is a blank, but sure it does not get accepted.

Comment: @Yiannis: the `\meaning` of a blank space is `blank space  ` (with two trailing spaces, hence the difficulty to get it into TeX).

Comment: @AhmedMusa If you have a beautiful and clever solution go ahead and post it:)

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch Thanks, so the one trailing space is the active part and the next its expansion?

Comment: @YiannisLazarides Not sure what you mean by "active part". The scheme for every catcode is the same: `<catcode description><space><character>`. For instance, `the letter<space>A`, or, say for a [catcode=10, charcode=64] token, `blank space<space>@`. To see that, try `\def\showmeaning#1{\showtokens\expandafter{\meaning#1}}\lccode32=64\lowercase{\showmeaning{ }}`.

Comment: @RyanReich: I just learned about this feature of pgf 2.10, and I have to say that it's a pity I didn't know about it (and that it wasn't available 4 years ago, when I needed exactly this and had to code it myself).  My use case is extracting a city name from a full postal address; in Poland, it is customary to give a zip code (of the form dd-ddd, where "d" is a digit) right before the city name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some times ago I created a similar parser function with LuaLaTeX. I used it to read text files, count and change some chars and put some LaTeX commands into the output.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{filecontents}

%create a test text file
\begin{filecontents*}{lorem.txt}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,
sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore 
magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam 
et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
\end{filecontents*}

%create a lua script file
\begin{filecontents*}{luaFunctions.lua}
```

```lua
function createReplaceTable()    
    replaceTable = {}

    -- create a table with all ASCII chars
    -- the name and(!) the value of each table item is the ASCII char
    -- this is important if the char shouldn't be replaced
    -- the table have 128 items each filled with the corresponding char
    for i = 1, 128, 1 do    
       replaceTable[string.char(i-1)] = string.char(i-1)
    end
end

function parseString(input)
    outputString = ""

    -- for each char in the given string we replace
    -- the char with the content of the table item
    -- because the table items have the same name like the chars
    -- we have access to the table item via the given char
    for i = 1, string.len(input) do
        char = input:sub(i, i)
        outputString = outputString..replaceTable[char]
    end

    tex.print(outputString)
end

function parseFile(fileName)
    -- open file
    local input = io.open('lorem.txt', 'r')

    -- parse each line
    for line in input:lines() do
        parseString(line)
    end
end

function fillReplaceTable()
    -- here we fill/override the replacements for each ASCII char
    replaceTable["L"] = "\\textbf{\\large L}\\marginpar{\\tiny 'L'(\\stepcounter{counterForL}\\#\\thecounterForL)}"
    replaceTable["o"] = "\\underline{o}"
    replaceTable["e"] = ""
end
```

```tex
\end{filecontents*}    

% read the external lua file to declare the functions,
% but without execute the Lua commands and functions
\directlua{dofile("luaFunctions.lua")}

%create and fill the tables
\directlua{createReplaceTable()}
\directlua{fillReplaceTable()}

% latex commands to execute the lua functions
\def\parseString#1{\directlua{parseString("#1")}}
\def\parseFile#1{\directlua{parseFile("#1")}}

%counter for the letter 'L'
\newcounter{counterForL}

\begin{document}
\parseString{%
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.%
}

\parseFile{lorem.txt}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How would you handle escaping of characters in Lua. Would you need to escape them in the text file or is there a mechanism to automate this. What happens when you read the character?

Answer (score 6):

Do you want something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{soul}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\xparserdef}{mmmm}
  {
   \cs_new:cpn { xparser_name_#1_state_#2_#3: } { #4 }
  }
\NewDocumentCommand{\xparserparse}{mm}
  {
   \tl_set:Nn \l_xparser_state_tl { initial }
   \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { \tl_to_str:n {#2} } 
   \tl_replace_all:NnV \l_tmpa_tl { ~ } \c_catcode_other_space_tl
   \tl_map_inline:Nn\l_tmpa_tl
     {
      \str_if_eq:VnF \l_xparser_state_tl { final }
        { \use:c { xparser_name_#1_state_ \l_xparser_state_tl _##1: } }
     }
  }
\tl_new:N \l_xparser_state_tl
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_replace_all:Nnn {NnV}
\NewDocumentCommand{\xparserswitch}{m}
  {
   \tl_set:Nn \l_xparser_state_tl { #1 }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\newcount\mycount

\xparserdef{myparser}{initial}{Z}{\advance\mycount by 1\relax Z}
\xparserdef{myparser}{initial}{a}{\hl{a}}
\xparserdef{myparser}{initial}{b}{} % do nothing
\xparserdef{myparser}{initial}{ }{\textcolor{red}{S}}
\xparserdef{myparser}{initial}{c}{\xparserswitch{final}}% done!
\xparserdef{myparser}{initial}{|}{\xparserswitch{bar}}
\xparserdef{myparser}{bar}{|}{\xparserswitch{initial}}

\xparserparse{myparser}{ZZZZa ab|aabaZ|baZbbbbbabaabccccZ}

There are \the\mycount\ Z's.

\end{document}
```

In the definition of `\xparserdef` there should probably be a check that the second argument is not `final`.

[image]

Notice that the `|` hides the fifth `Z` and that the sixth is ignored as we are in state `final`. The macros also allow to define an action for "space" (thanks to Bruno Le Floch for suggesting the way).

Comment: Good, but that will still choke on spaces. You need to use `\futurelet` to do that properly, or perhaps `\tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { \tl_to_str:n {#2} } \tl_replace_all:Nno \l_tmpa_tl { ~ } { \c_other_space_tl } \tl_map_inline:Nn\l_tmpa_tl { ... }`.

Answer (score 3):

So far, have managed to keep the parser quiet and save typing by looping through the alphabet using a `\@tfor` and creating the macros.

Tried also PGF's `@foreach` unsuccessfully and would welcome some pointers in this respect.

```
% Letter definitions
\@tfor\next:=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890[].;:-=\  \do{%
  \def\command@factory#1{%
  \pgfparserdef{myparser}{initial}{\meaning #1}{\textcolor{purple}{#1}}%
  }
 \expandafter\command@factory\next
}
```

For the space, if it is entered as `\`, it appears to be working (but would have been better, if the parser would work without such hand marking.

Interestingly, if one adds `\lipsum` in the alphabets above i.e,

```
 abcdef\lipsum g...
```

It will get parsed and expanded as a single character (it will get fully printed in purple) in the MWE below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepgfmodule{parser}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\newcount\mycount

% Letter definitions
\@tfor\next:=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890[].;:-=\lipsum\space\ \do{%
  \def\command@factory#1{%
  \pgfparserdef{myparser}{initial}{\meaning #1}{\textcolor{purple}{#1}}%
  }
 \expandafter\command@factory\next
}

%\foreach \x in {a,...,z} {\command@factory\x}

\pgfparserdef{myparser}{initial}{the letter Z}{\advance\mycount by 1\relax Z}
\pgfparserdef{myparser}{initial}{the letter a}{\hl{a}}
\pgfparserdef{myparser}{initial}{the letter b}{} % do nothing
\pgfparserdef{myparser}{initial}{the letter c}{c} % do nothing
\pgfparserdef{myparser}{initial}{the letter G}{\textcolor{blue}{George}}
\pgfparserdef{myparser}{initial}{the character !}{\pgfparserswitch{final}}% done!

\pgfparserparse{myparser}ZZZZaabaabaZebabbdbQG012\ 345booopsbabaabggg[g][1=;].cccc\lipsum!! 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Without looking into it at all, I'm guessing that `\foreach` breaks because it executes each iteration in a group, and `\pgfparserdef` is local.  Try setting `\globaldefs=1` (this was suggested in an answer here that I can't find right now).

Comment: Also, thanks for answering a question I didn't ask but was wondering about: how the parser handles macros.  Apparently it does the logical thing and treats them as a single token with a specific meaning.  Since you set the behavior of the parser on `\lipsum` itself, it will pick up that token as a single entity.  (If you hadn't, I bet it would have raised an error).

Comment: @Yiannis: I don't know the file that defines \pgfparserdef, but there is a spurious space in the definition.

Answer (score 2):

Not used this before but it looks like if you change a copy at line 45 from

```
    \ifx\pgf@parser@action\relax%
      \PackageError{pgfparse}{Unexpected character
        '\meaning\pgf@parser@symbol' in parser '\pgf@parser' in state
        '\pgf@parser@state'}{}%
    \fi%
```

to

```
    \ifx\pgf@parser@action\relax%
      \PackageWarning{pgfparse}{Unexpected character
        '\meaning\pgf@parser@symbol' in parser '\pgf@parser' in state
        '\pgf@parser@state'}{}%
    \fi%
```

It's ignored with a warning, or if you just lost those lines it would be silently ignored.

Comment: Then the `silence` package should be a better way to do that, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{ltxkeys}
\makeatletter

\new@def*\cptifcmdeqTF#1{\expandafter\ifcseqTF\cpt@car#1\cpt@quark\car@nil}
\cptswap{ }{\let\cptblankspace= }
\new@def*\cptendparse{\@gobble\cptendparse}
\newletcs\cptstopparse\cptendparse
\ltxkeys@declarekeys*[CPT]{parserparse}[cpt@parser@]{%
  cmd/id/currparser;
  cmd/state/initial;
}
% \cptparserdef{<parserid>}{<state>}{\meaning<token>}{<defn>}
\robust@def\cptparserdef#1#2#3#4{%
  \long\csn@edef{cpt@parser@#1@#2@#3}{\unexpanded{#4}}%
}
% \ParserParseDef{<keyval>}{<tokenlist>}{<defn>}
% Use '#1' in <defn> to access the current token of <tokenlist>.
\robust@def*\ParserParseDef{\cpt@teststopt\cpt@ParserParseDef{}}
\robust@def\cpt@ParserParseDef[#1]#2#3{%
  \let\ifcpt@parser@st\ifcpt@st
  \ltxkeys@launchkeys[CPT]{parserparse}{#1}%
  \ifcpt@parser@st\expandafter\expandafter\fi
  \cpttfor#2\dofor{%
    \cptifcmdeqTF{##1}\cptblankspace{%
      % Current system definition for space token:
      \cptparserdef{\cpt@parser@id}{\cpt@parser@state}
        {blank space\@space\@space}{\@space}%
    }{%
      \edef\parser@tempa{\cpttrimspace{##1}}%
      \edef\parser@tempa{\expandafter\meaning\parser@tempa}%
      \cptparserdef{\cpt@parser@id}{\cpt@parser@state}{\parser@tempa}{#3}%
    }%
  }%
}
% \ParserParseSelectDef{<keyval>}{<tokenlist>}
% <tokenlist> -> {<token>}{<defn>}
% You can use '#1' in <defn> to access the first token of the current
% pair of <tokenlist>.
\robust@def*\ParserParseSelectDef{\cpt@teststopt\cpt@ParserParseSelectDef{}}
\robust@def\cpt@ParserParseSelectDef[#1]#2{%
  \let\ifcpt@parser@st\ifcpt@st
  \ltxkeys@launchkeys[CPT]{parserparse}{#1}%
  \begingroup
  \@tempcnta\z@pt
  \def\parser@do##1{%
    \cptifcmdeqTF{##1}\parser@do{}{%
      \advance\@tempcnta\@ne\parser@do
    }%
  }%
  \ifcpt@parser@st\expandafter\expandafter\fi
  \parser@do#2\parser@do
  \ifodd\@tempcnta
    \cpt@err{User list items not pairwise balanced}
      {List items for \noexpand\ParserParseSelectDef
      must be even in number}%
  \fi
  \endgroup
  \def\parser@do##1##2{%
    \cptifcmdeqTF{##1}\parser@do{}{%
      \cptifcmdeqTF{##1}\cptblankspace{%
        % Current user definition for space token:
        \cptparserdef{\cpt@parser@id}{\cpt@parser@state}
          {blank space\@space\@space}{##2}%
      }{%
        \edef\parser@tempa{\cpttrimspace{##1}}%
        \edef\parser@tempa{\expandafter\meaning\parser@tempa}%
        % This trick is to enable '#1' to be used in <defn> to access the
        % first token of the current pair of <tokenlist>.
        \def\reserved@a####1{\@temptokena{##2}}%
        \reserved@a{##1}%
        \def\reserved@a####1{%
          \cptparserdef{\cpt@parser@id}{\cpt@parser@state}{\parser@tempa}{####1}%
        }%
        \expandafter\reserved@a\expandafter{\the\@temptokena}%
      }%
      \parser@do
    }%
  }%
  \ifcpt@parser@st\expandafter\expandafter\fi
  \parser@do#2\parser@do\parser@do
}
\robust@def*\cptparserparse{\cpt@testopt\cpt@parserparse@a{}}
\robust@def*\cpt@parserparse@a[#1]{%
  \ltxkeys@launchkeys[CPT]{parserparse}{#1}%
  % Gobble any space after ']'. If the user needs any space after ']',
  % he has to insert an explicit space token:
  \expandafter\cpt@parserparse@b\romannumeral-`\q\noexpand
}
\robust@def*\cpt@parserparse@b{%
  \futurelet\cpt@parsersymbol\cpt@parserparse@c
}
\robust@def*\cpt@parserparse@c{%
  \ifx\cpt@parsersymbol\cptendparse
    \let\cpt@parseraction\relax
    \def\cpt@parserparse@d{\let\cpt@parserignore=}%
  \else
    \def\cpt@parserparse@d{%
      \afterassignment\cpt@parserparse@b\let\cpt@parserignore= %
    }%
    \letcstocsn\cpt@parseraction{cpt@parser@\cpt@parser@id
      @\cpt@parser@state @\meaning\cpt@parsersymbol}%
    \ifdefTF\cpt@parseraction{}{%
      \cpt@err{Unexpected character '\meaning\cpt@parsersymbol'
        in parser '\cpt@parser@id' of state '\cpt@parser@state'}\@ehc
    }%
  \fi
  \cpt@parseraction
  \cpt@parserparse@d
}
\edef\cptparserchars{%
  abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ%
  1234567890\cpt@otherchars\noexpand\cptblankspace
}

% Examples:
\newcommand*\sometext[1][1]{%
  \cptdotimes{#1}{Here is some sample text that should fit in the given space.}
}
\cptrobustify\sometext

% Default system definitions; initialization is by the user:
\ParserParseDef*[id=myparser,state=initial]\cptparserchars
{\textcolor{orange}{#1}}

% Peculiar user definitions:
\ParserParseSelectDef[id=myparser,state=initial]{%
  {Z}{\advance\mycount\@ne\textcolor{red}{\fbox{#1}}}
  {a}{\hl{a}} {b}{} {c}{c}
  {G}{\textcolor{blue}{George}}
  {!}{This is exclamation mark.}
  {\cptblankspace}{\textcolor{green}{\texttt{@}}}
  {\sometext}{\textcolor{purple}{#1}}
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\newcount\mycount
\noindent
\cptparserparse[id=myparser,state=initial]
Z ABC XYZ aabaaba Z ebab QOG 012345 booops babaab egg [foo]/[1=;].cccc.
\sometext!\cptendparse

\par\medskip\noindent
Number of character \textcolor{red}{\texttt{\fbox{Z}}} in token list: \number\mycount.

\end{document}
```

[image]

**To-do**

What happens to brace-groups in the given token list? For example, what happens to `{ZZZaababa}` in the following?

```
\cptparserparse{myparser}Z {ZZZaababa}.cccc!
```

Should parsing start anew locally in `{ZZZaababa}`? In selective sanitization, each brace-group is treated according to specific instructions for brace-groups.

Also, what level of nesting of brace-groups should the instructions apply to? For example, how far should parsing go in

```
\cptparserparse{myparser}Z {{{{{x{ZZZaababa}}}}}}.cccc!
```

Comment: Thanks - this is a very good tip.However, most of my examples and responses use common constructs such as for-loops, as they make them more understandable.

Comment: Does the output look like what you wanted?

Comment: It is more or less. I will check it out a bit later and give you a proper response, as I need to familiarize myself with `catoptions` to understand your code. Thanks for all the effort.

Comment: If the code is useful I can remove the dependence on *catoptions* package.

Comment: Thanks - I am trying to build a generalized parser and thought this would be easier than from scratch. Not to worry about further edits. I will post a more specific question over the next few days and ping you here.